# viewWillAppear method not getting called in iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I'm using Xcode 4.2. I set the deployment target as 4.2. I created an app with the view hierarchy as `UIViewController` > `UITabBarController` > `UINavigationController` > `UIViewController`.It is working fine with iOS 5. But for iOS 4.2, the `viewWillAppear`  method is not getting called. what would be the reason for this?

Comment: Quick question, you have an UITabBarController inside an UIViewController? Why?

Comment: I had the same issue. Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089287/in-ios-4-x-or-lower-viewdidappear-method-is-not-getting-called-while-adding-sub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a custom UIViewController as top level VC, you need to pass the viewWillAppear event to the UITabBarController